# Обернуть JSON в массив

Tags: c#, wpf

Как добавить массив в json? Нужно просто обернуть существующие данные в квадратные скобки. Как в JSON ниже.

```cs
using (StreamWriter w = File.CreateText("test.json"))
{
    JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
    serializer.Serialize(w, MyModel);
    w.Close();
}
```

```
[
  {
    "data":[
       {
        "Latitude":  37.7668,
        "Longitude": -122.3959,
        "Address":   ""
      },
      {
        "Latitude":  37.7668,
        "Longitude": -122.3959,
        "Address":   ""
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JSON можно рассматривать как представление CLR объекта в виде строки. В таком случае, само собой напрашивается решение в виде оборачивания этого объекта в массив, чтобы на выходе получить представление объекта, завернутого в массив.

```cs
serializer.Serialize(w, new [] { MyModel });
```